# This Ajax Request is not responding to the corresponding JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script 
<script>

function kick_start(){
var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="student.json";

xml.open("GET", url, true);
xml.send();


xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status==200){
var file=JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
var data=document.getElementById("demo"); 
data.innerHTML=file.Name;
}
}
data.innerHTML="Fetching Data..........";
}



</script>
<script>kick_start()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And JSON file is:

```
{"Name":"Arman","ID":1312038;"Department":"NAME"}
```

I tried a lot to run this HTML file to fetch data from the JSON file via Ajax request. But Something is wrong.I save both the file in the same directory. What can I do?

Comment: Any error in `console` or `network-tab` ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 2):

When you're setting the `data.innerHTML` to "Fetching Data", `data` is not the element at that point, because it only becomes the element when the ajax completes. This will trigger an error in the console – press F12 to take a look.

To solve that, move the `var data = ...` line out of the readystatechange function.

Another problem is your JSON isn't valid, you have `;` which should be a comma. You can validate it on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).